# Mean of a random sample from a Uniform Distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, sampling

The following question:

[image]

has the following answer:

[image]

The only part I don't understand is why they put E in front of 2X at the very beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bias of $2\overline{X}$ is given by $B(2\overline{X}) = E(2\overline{X}) - \alpha$. Then they proceeded to show the bias was nonzero because $E(2\overline{X}) = 1 + \alpha$.